# What is the meaning of verb (te form) + くって？

Tags: parsing

> きっと旅立ってくってわかってるんだ

My friend translate for me as "I know I will depart on a journey"

旅立って is te form of 旅立つ
わかって is te form of わかる
then why add くって?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 「Verb in Te-Form + くって」

is the colloquial form of

> 「Verb in Te-Form + いくって」

So, 「旅立ってく」＝「旅立っていく」 = "to go on a trip"

Not to confuse you, but I will say that in the phrase:

> 「旅立**って**く**って**わかってるんだ」

The **first** 「って」 is part of the te-form and the **second** 「って」 is the informal version of the quotative particle 「と」.